# QChart padding is too big which causes charts compression

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, charts, pyqt

I create some charts and filling main window with them.

The main thing is that i can't decrease the inner (white colored) padding of the `QChart` and this causes charts compression and Y axis values disappearing.
[image]

Here is the code as a minimum reproducible example:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide6 import QtCharts, QtGui


import random


class Chart(QtCharts.QChart):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_series()
        self.createDefaultAxes()

        self.legend().setVisible(True)
        self.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)

    def create_series(self, s=3):
        for j in range(s):
            series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
            if j == 0:
                for i in range(150):
                    if i % 10 == 0:
                        series.append(i, random.randint(0, 10))
                    else:
                        series.append(i, 2)
                self.addSeries(series)


class ChartView(QtCharts.QChartView):
    def __init__(self, chart):
        super().__init__()

        self.setChart(chart)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRubberBand(QtCharts.QChartView.RectangleRubberBand)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setObjectName('central_widget')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)

        for _ in range(6):
            chart_view = self.create_chart_view()
            self.layout.addWidget(chart_view)

        self.setStyleSheet('#central_widget{background: red}')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def create_chart_view(self):
        chart = Chart()
        chart_view = ChartView(chart=chart)
        return chart_view


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I've found how to setup red and yellow areas. But can't figure out which widget can handle white area...

Comment: Did you try to reduce the values of the `self.layout().setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)` call?

Comment: @MarcoF. this can setup yellow area only

Comment: when the yellow area becomes smaller, the chart also gets more space, or not? And you could also try `chart->setMargins()`

Comment: @yes. yellow area allows charts some space, but still not enough. There is way too much blank (white) space (white margins and spacing between series_icon / series_name) in compare with too compressed charts.

Comment: Did you try [`setMargins`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qchart.html#margins-prop)? Also, if you want to show multiple charts, you should consider using graphics layout. Also check the chart's contents margins, not only that of its layout. Please check the documentation of all members, including those inherited by the base classes (in this case, QGraphicsWidget).

Comment: @MarcoF. thank you so much! setMargins() helped. (Still trying to figure out how to setup contentSpacing between series name and chart)

Comment: @Mika ok. For future reference, since you've been asking lots of questions about these topics lately, I suggest you to take your time to always check the **full** documentation of the objects you're using (including that about those from which they inherit) and do self-test examples based on simple situations in order to understand how those objects work. This also includes studying the *whole* documentation about the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) and *all* its related classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use additionally setMargin on your chart

```
chart->setMargins()
```

Comment: That works perfectly. But, chart.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) is also needed, to delete outer margins.